# Can not invoke bean action method in onclick attribute of a ui component

Tags: jsf, onclick, action

```
<h:outputLink value="/4JVA-157292-war/supinfo/auth/mycar.xhtml">Car</h:outputLink>
<h:outputLink value="Log Out" onclick="${loginController.logout()}" />
```

As you see, If i click the Car link. I will excute the `${loginController.logout()}`, but if i delete the Log out. I will go into the car page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`<h:ouputLink>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/outputLink.html) component is used to render plain `a` anchor element with its `href` attribute evaluated as `value` attribute of `<h:outputLink>` with the query parameters attached in case the component has `<f:param>` tags as its children.

`<h:ouputLink>` is **not used** to execute server-side actions as you wrongly seemed to expect. You may have confused it with a [`<h:commandLink>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/commandLink.html) component that is used to trigger a server-side action via a JavaScript call.

If you want to call the action method you must switch to a command comnponent (or its derivative) like `<h:commandLink>`. Its `action` attribute should point to the desired action method, like so:

```
<h:commandLink value="Log out" action="#{loginController.logout}" />
```

In this way you will be able to execute the bean action method.

Also it is worth noting that since JSF 2.0 there has been an `<h:link>` component that is useful for handling application-wide navigation. It takes a navigation case outcome in its `outcome` attribute thus leaving `<h:outputLink>` component useful for links to external resources.

For more information on the subject read the following answer: [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink).

---

As to the cause of the problem you faced, `onclick` attribute is rendered as `onclick` event handler of the generated `a` element that responds to a click event on the HTML element it is attached to. In case the event is fired a client-side JavaScript code is called (by function call `onclick` points to or by executing inline code that is contained therein). Do note that `onclick` runs on the client (in JavaScript context within web browser) while `action` runs on the server (executes Java code depending on the submit button pressed within web server).

Usage of `onclick` may be fruitful at least in the following circumstances:

- in case it is used in conjunction with a *command component* it may **stop form submission** to the server if some client-side requirements are not met (i.e. confirm dialog was shown and cancel button was pressed, or client-side validation failed) as soon as the event will be fired *before* any consecutive events associated with the element (like form submission):

  ```
  <h:commandLink value="Delete item" action="#{bean.delete(item)}" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");" ... />
  ```

  or

  ```
  <h:commandLink value="Submit data" action="#{bean.action}" onclick="return inputValid();" ... />
  ```

  with

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function inputValid() {
          var isInputValid = ...;
          //decide what's valid or not and set variable to true/false accordingly
          return isInputValid;
      }
  </script>
  ```
- it may be used to **trigger some GUI changes**, especially when used in conjunction with *non-command components*, like in:

  ```
  <h:button value="Show dialog" onclick="showDialog(); return false;" ... />
  ```

Comment: Would be nice if you explained actual meaning/appliance/working of `onclick`, too, as the OP apparently completely misunderstood it.

Comment: Yup, that point is completely missing in the answer. I will update it soon. Thanks!

Comment: @skuntsel Thx for your explain. It's very clear for me now.