# Change Rendered of datatable in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I want to change rendered of datatable with commandbutton's onclick()
     method. But It didn't work.I mean re-render datatable after I change rendered .What can I do ?

In my backing bean :

```
private boolean projetabloaktif=false;
```

I declare a variable for change rendered of datatable

```
public void projerendered(){
    this.projetabloaktif=true;
}
```

Here I activate.

```
public void projederendered(){
    this.projetabloaktif=false;
}
```

Here I disactivate.

Below is my jsf page!

```
            <h:commandButton value="PROJE AKTIF" onclick="#{kntrl.projerendered()}">     
                <f:ajax execute="proje" render="proje:projetablo"/>
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton value="PROJE DEAKTIF" onclick="#{kntrl.projederendered()}" >
            <f:ajax execute="proje" render="proje:projetablo"/>
            </h:commandButton>


            <h:dataTable border="1" cellpadding="7px" value="#{kntrl.projelistedondur()}" var="proje"  id="projetablo" rendered="#{kntrl.projetabloaktif}">
                <h:column >
                    <f:facet name="header" >Proje Adı</f:facet>
                        #{proje.projead}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Proje Konusu</f:facet>
                        #{proje.projekonu}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Proje Durumu</f:facet>
                        #{proje.projedurum}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Proje Görevi</f:facet>
                        #{proje.projegorev}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Proje Başlangıç Tarihi</f:facet>
                        #{proje.projebastar}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Proje Bitiş Tarihi</f:facet>
                        #{proje.projebittar}
                </h:column>

            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Where did you read/learn that the 'onClick' attributes call a server-side java method? Please don't use that tutorial... And your actual problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623664/can-not-invoke-bean-action-method-in-onclick-attribute-of-houtputlink Not the rendering part but that the 'method' is not called when you expect it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not invoke bean action method in onclick attribute of h:outputLink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623664/can-not-invoke-bean-action-method-in-onclick-attribute-of-houtputlink)

Comment: Thank you so much.You're absolutely right.I did it with action method .And change render="proje:projetablo" to render=":proje :projetablo"